# Wrapping a HTML element in Visual Studio Code using Emmet

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, emmet

I am using VSC for developing html pages. It's been a great experience using emmet with VSC, but often I find in a situation where I have to wrap a set of elements with a div, but have to use emmet on a single line and then cut paste the end tag at the end of the set of elements I want to map.

Is there any way where I can use emmet and automatically wrap the output of emmet around a set of selected elements?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try the `Emmet: Wrap with Abbreviation` command:

[image]

Comment: If you need wrapping each line by a tag, just add the * as a sufix to the tag.    ie:        1. Select lines 2. Select Emmet Wrap Individual Lines with Abbreviation  3. Type in command 
  "li*"

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way is to use a key binding, you can assign your own key for this.
`file > preference > keyboard shortcuts > editkeybindings` and assign your own

```
[{ "key": "ctrl+shift+g", "command":"editor.emmet.action.wrapWithAbbreviation", "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly" }]
```