# In Visual Studio Code wrap an HTML tag on a single line with Emmet

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

I know how to [wrap a single line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44480051/wrapping-a-html-element-in-visual-studio-code-using-emmet/44556731#44556731) of text in an HTML tag with Emmet by using **Wrap with Abbreviation**. It works. However, it produces the following output:

```
<h1>
    HTML5
</h1>
```

What I want is this:

```
<h1>HTML5</h1>
```

I can make some progress with this in my User Settings:

```
"emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
    "html": {
        "tag_nl": false            
    }
}
```

However, my output then looks like this, with extra whitespace:

```
<h1>    HTML5 </h1>
```

Oddly, if want to individually wrap a selection that contains multiple lines, visual studio behaves as I want. It is just individual lines that cause this behavior. For instance, if want to wrap this:

```
foo
bar
```

I end up with this, which is what I what I want:

```
<h1>foo</h1>
<h1>bar</h1>
```

Is there a way to sort this out? I just want to wrap some text in a tag with no fancy formatting:

```
<h1>HTML5</h1>
```

It is perhaps worth pointing out that WebStorm and Atom wrap as I expected. This is a Visual Studio Code specific thing.

Comment: Looks like a bug. You can try creating an issue https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code:

```
"emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
    "html": {
        "tag_nl": false            
    }
}
```

It works now perfectly with single line selection, but is still buggy with multiple lines (extra tabs & spaces added)